# The best way to rephrase the sentence

Tags: past-perfect

Task on translating:

> Although she turned away, he had seen she had burst into tears.

Is there too much redundancy here ("had seen","had burst")?

Is it better to say:

> She turned away, no sooner he had seen than she burst into tears (it's slightly awkward because of the unlogical succession of actions in "no sooner" construction. How could it be rewritten with this construction?).

or

> She turned away but not before he saw she had burst into tears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He sees her burst into tears before she turns away.

MOST RECENT...........................OLDEST
She turns away.  ........He sees her burst into tears

So we can cast his seeing in the past perfect and her turning away in the simple past.

As for the bursting into tears, we don't need to locate that action in time with a tense, as it is something he perceives; the bursting-into-tears is coincident with the time of his perception.

> She *turned away*, but not before he *had seen* her *burst* into tears.

The secondary complement of verbs of perception can be headed by the bare infinitive.

> I saw *him* **go**.
>
> I felt *the bee* **sting** my foot.
>
> They heard *the vase* **shatter** on the floor.
>
> ... but not before he had seen *her* **burst** into tears.

Stylistically, from the point of view of verbal economy and temporal clarity, a simple infinitive complement is better here than a *that*-clause with a tensed verb; a tense is required in the *that*-clause but that tense is unnecessary and unwanted in the sentence as a whole.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in replying. So, I could use "She turned away, but after he had seen her burst into tears." as  well as you variant. And it would live up to the meaning and context of the picture we have?

Comment: *She turned away ... after he had seen **her burst into tears**.*  is also OK. The main thing is that you can simplify the sentence and improve its clarity by not using a *that*-clause with a finite verb as the complement of "he had seen", the verb of perception.